# Is it possible to produce 3 nested layers in a single Eloquent query?

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

I’m trying to produce json for an Ajax response to a Vue frontend to represent a reactions system, output similar to what you may see in Facebook. A post has reaction types (like, love, angry) and each of those reaction types will have users that have registered that reaction.

The output I’m looking for in order to keep most of the work in the controller so that the frontend doesn’t have to loop through the output to total up counts is like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 258,
    "reactions": [
      {
        "type": "like",
        "count": 2,
        "names": [
          {
            "user_id": 1,
            "first_name": "Drew",
          },
          {
            "user_id": 2,
            "first_name": "Kathy",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "angry",
        "count": 3,
        "names": [
          {
            "user_id": 3,
            "first_name": "Bob",
          },
          {
            "user_id": 4,
            "first_name": "Fred",
          },
          {
            "user_id": 5,
            "first_name": "Anne",
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

I can easily get the first two layers:

```
return Post::latest()
    ->with('user:id,first_name')
    ->with(['postReactions' => function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::table('post_reactions'))
            ->select('post_id', 'type', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
            ->groupBy('post_id', 'type');
    }])
```

And I’ve been able to do various versions of it with the detail in second level but without the summary count.

In my head I want to add a nested “with” in the postReactions subquery, something like:

```
return Post::latest()
    ->with('user:id,first_name')
    ->with(['postReactions' => function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::table('post_reactions'))
            ->select('post_id', 'type', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
            ->groupBy('post_id', 'type');
        $query->with('user:id,first_name');
    }])
```

Is this possible or do I need to iterate through my initial result to add the name detail?

Answer (score -1):

There's built-in [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method for you.

As for the nested relationships, they will get the structure you want if you chain the nested relation with a dot convention:

```php
->with('reactions.names')
```

Of course, I'm assuming these the actual names of your relations.

Comment: I should have said: I can get all the data into the output ok, including the withCount() but I can only do it at two levels i.e. with the reactions and names of users with those reactions on the same. I can work with that if I have to but if I can get it into the structure above from the one query, there's no iterating to do either in the controller or the frontend.